# How to combine Linphone with Android SIP stack

Tags: android, sip, linphone

I am using Liphone to register towards a SIP server, but then I want to use Android SIP manager to initiate the outgoing call. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean [SipManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager) class?